# How to insert a Drupal block into a PDF generated by TCPDF

Tags: drupal, pdf, tcpdf

I am using Drupal 7. I made use of print module and TCPDF library to generate a downloadable PDF on specific node types. Now I would like to insert a Custom Drupal Block (Bookmarks for PDF) into the Downloadable PDF file. Is there any option that I could do to insert this block into the PDF.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can enter whatever you want in the corresponding tpl.php pages. 
Find the template for pdf files in "print" module's folder - usually sites/all/modules/print/print_pdf.tpl.php .

You can print any block, views, or any custom text.